# Adding Function from another python file

Tags: python, function

I'm a python beginner and I'm trying to read a function from one python file into another.  However I am getting stuck with an import error.  My directories are like this:

test folder

- plot.py
- setup folder containing (mapsetup.py, empty __init __.py file)

in **mapsetup.py** I have the following code:

```
def read_files (project_name):   
  extent_dir =(os.path.join (dir['extents_dir'],project_name, 'extent_'  + project_name + '.shp') )
```

and then in **plot.py** I have this

```
project_name = str(input())

sys.path.append('/Users/Documents/python/test/setup')
from setup.mapsetup import read_files
```

but I keep getting this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'read_files' from 'setup.mapsetup'

Comment: Is the test folder on your Python path? Usually this means that the test folder is either your current working directory, or you explicitly added it to the Python path through a different means (e.g. the env var `PYTHONPATH`)

Comment: I think if `/setup` is in the path then you don't want `setup.` in the import statement

Comment: @Anentropic Given that they put a `__init__.py` file in `setup`, I think its same to assume that they do want it to be a package.

Comment: yes, perhaps it should be `sys.path.append('/Users/Documents/python/test')` ?

Comment: @Brian the test folder should be my current working directory.  I tried changing it to sys.path.append('/Users/Documents/python/test') but still same error comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably there is a function called `read_files` (check spelling).

There is a double use of the `setup` in path. So remove one or the other.

like this:

```py
# either
sys.path.append('/Users/Documents/python/test/setup')
from mapsetup import read_files    # <-- removed

# or this
sys.path.append('/Users/Documents/python/test')   # <-- removed
from setup.mapsetup import read_files
```

Note,  it you are using an editor like `vscode`, the intellisense will usually pick all this up as you are typing, so you will know that you are in the right place. very helpful.

Comment: thankyou, i am using vscode! I tried restarting VSCode and running this again and it worked